# Modifying SettingsPage.xaml in vs2017 Windows Template Studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-template-studio

I am using Windows Template Studio to create an application with a modifiable theme. Is it possible to add new contents on the settings page? There are 3 themes available currently: light, dark and default. I would like to add another one for example blue. There is an `ElementTheme` property but I can't modify it since ElementTheme.cs is from metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Template Studio doesn't create an app, it creates the start of an app. What is generated is intended to be a starting point and should be modified as appropriate for your circumstances.

The generated settings page includes the ability to select light or dark theme. Feel free to support either, or neither of these as appropriate. Implementing custom themes should be done in the same way as an app created from a blank template. Just remove anything WTS puts there you don't need or want.

The [official UWP docs have some guidance on creating custom themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources).

There is also [an app in the store to help you create custom themes for your app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9N2XD3Q8X57C).

See also, [this question about creating custom themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533783/custom-themes-in-uwp-application).

There are instructions on further extending the settings page at https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/blob/dev/docs/pages/settings.md