# Change Windows App Icon depending on dark/light mode

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Some of the icons in Windows 10 & 11 change depending on whether Windows is set to light or dark mode.

Is there a way I can have the app icon for my WPF app change depending on the current mode?

---

Here is an example of the Windows 10 store icon changing

[image: Store icon changing with modes]

And here is an example of some of the icons changing on Windows 11
[image: Windows 11 light/dark modes]

Comment: Rather than changing only icons you need to add themes support into your application. There are control libraries with themes support, perhaps the easiest way.

Comment: Otherwise [check windows theme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56007857/1997232) and [change icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43179090/1997232).

Comment: I have theme support in the application but that doesn't help if the app isn't running

Comment: If you are talking about desktop shortcuts, then look carefully at your screenshot, icons are the same. I don't know much about app store icons, I guess they have some OS switching support for that. You wouldn't be able to achieve it for wpf application (unless you mean [tag:uwp]) easily.

Comment: The alarms and clock icon has changed as well. I thought it was probably something the OS is doing but I would like to know if there is a way. I know you can supply different images for the start menu on Windows 10 using a VisualElementsManifest.xml file and thought maybe there was an undocumented way to add different images for light/dark modes.

Comment: There [is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39533783/1997232), `RequestedTheme="Light"`. No idea how you apply icon to a theme though.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but that article refers to UWP and I am asking about WPF. Also that article is talking about changing the theme in-app during runtime. I am talking about changing the short-cut icon on the start menu, even when the app isn't running.